# Looping through a list of dictionaries in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm extremely new to python and I have been having trouble creating a loop for my dictionary which contains a list of dictionaries. I'd appreciate the help!

```
mylist = {'ID_01': [{'blood type': 'A',
                     'Age': '15',
                     'eye colour': 'Green',
                     'Location': 'Toronto',
                     'Initial Score': '30',
                     'Final Score': '50'},
                    {'blood type': 'B',
                     'Age': '20',
                     'eye colour': 'Green',
                     'Location': 'Tokyo',
                     'Initial Score': '50',
                     'Final Score': '80'}],
          'ID_02': [{'blood type': 'C',
                     'Age': '10',
                     'eye colour': 'Blue',
                     'Location': 'Toronto',
                     'Initial Score': '90',
                     'Final Score': '100'},
                    {'blood type': 'D',
                     'Age': '13',
                     'eye colour': 'Blue',
                     'Location': 'Tokyo',
                     'Initial Score': '60',
                     'Final Score': '90'}]}


new_dictionary = {}
```

if location is Toronto, add ID
and
if location is tokyo, check if initial score of Tokyo (50) is smaller than initial score of Toronto (30) AND if final score of Tokyo (80) is bigger than the initial score of Toronto(30) but smaller than the final score of Toronto, if yes, add all data associated with that ID to new_dictionary.

a loop to add the `ID` data to `new_dictionary` if :

`initial score of tokyo < initial score of toronto`

AND

`initial score of toronto < final score of tokyo < final score of toronto`

Thank You!

Comment: @hibou Does your example list have 1 id, or 2?

Comment: hey! it has one ID, but two dictionaries corresponding to that ID.  so that ID_01 has both dictionaries

Comment: How are we supposed to add ids when there is only 1?

Comment: hey! sorry about that, I guess i was unclear, i edited my question to better reflect what I meant :( !

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
mylist = {'ID_01': [{'blood type': 'A',
                     'Age': '15',
                     'eye colour': 'Green',
                     'Location': 'Toronto',
                     'Initial Score': '30',
                     'Final Score': '50'}],
          'ID_02': [{'blood type': 'B',
                     'Age': '10',
                     'eye colour': 'Blue',
                     'Location': 'Tokyo',
                     'Initial Score': '50',
                     'Final Score': '80'}]}

initial_score_of_tokyo = [mylist[ID][0]["Initial Score"] for ID in mylist.keys() if mylist[ID][0]['Location'] == 'Tokyo'][0]
initial_score_of_toronto = [mylist[ID][0]["Initial Score"] for ID in mylist.keys() if mylist[ID][0]['Location'] == 'Toronto'][0]
final_score_of_tokyo = [mylist[ID][0]["Final Score"] for ID in mylist.keys() if mylist[ID][0]['Location'] == 'Tokyo'][0]
final_score_of_toronto = [mylist[ID][0]["Final Score"] for ID in mylist.keys() if mylist[ID][0]['Location'] == 'Toronto'][0]


new_dictionary = {}

for ID in mylist.keys():
    if mylist[ID][0]['Location'] == 'Toronto' or (initial_score_of_tokyo < initial_score_of_toronto and initial_score_of_toronto < final_score_of_tokyo < final_score_of_toronto):
          new_dictionary.update({ID:mylist[ID]})

print(new_dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'ID_01': [{'blood type': 'A',
            'Age': '15',
            'eye colour': 'Green',
            'Location': 'Toronto',
            'Initial Score': '30',
            'Final Score': '50'}]}
```

Comment: Hey! thank you so much for replying, both dictionaries belong to the same ID, you separated each dictionary into one ID (giving me two ID's) which is not what my dataset looks like (':.